# mysql query takes 400 sec to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

Here is the query that takes 400 sec to load. I tried in mysql directly . If i try subqueries separately, all get executed in less than 0.01 sec. 
query afer union all exuecutes in 40 sec. query before union all executes in 1 sec.

sales table and salesaff table both contains about 12K records each. The purpose of this query is when vendor=affiliate in sales table, then i need to add rows from salesaff table which id match with search criteria in sales table.

```
 (
 SELECT 'no' AS aff, ss.orderid,ss.saletype,ss.price,ss.salests 
    FROM sales ss 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 
        ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
  ) 

 UNION ALL 

 ( 
 SELECT 'yes' AS aff, sf.orderid,sf.saletype,sf.price,sf.salests 
 FROM salesaff sf 
 WHERE sf.vendor=sf.affiliate AND 
 sf.orderid IN (SELECT ss.orderid from sales ss WHERE 1=1 
               AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
               GROUP BY ss.orderid ) 
 ) 

 ORDER BY salests DESC
```

Comment: What's with the Where 1=1 business? no need for that.  Aslo, please format your SQL so we can read it.

Comment: Try without the order by clause and see how it goes.

Comment: 1=1 is to write dynamic query so that i can add AND column=condition from script. I removed 1=1 and tried no change in perfermance.

Comment: second query itself takes 40 sec, without order by 4 sec is improved.

Comment: Try using EXPLAIN to see where the bottleneck is.  http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

Comment: 2 composite indices `sales(vendor,orderid)`,`sales(affiliate,orderid)` and one on `salesaff(vendor,affiliate,orderid)` might improve things.

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch this:

```
EXPLAIN ( SELECT 'no' AS aff, ss.orderid,ss.saletype,ss.price,ss.salests FROM sales ss WHERE 1=1 AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') )

UNION ALL

( SELECT 'yes' AS aff, sf.orderid,sf.saletype,sf.price,sf.salests FROM salesaff sf WHERE sf.vendor=sf.affiliate AND

sf.orderid IN ( SELECT ss.orderid from sales ss WHERE 1=1 AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') GROUP BY ss.orderid ) )

ORDER BY salests DESC
```

check if the "key" column is never null, otherwise add the indexes to the mentioned columns.

It that doesn't help, check this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7806/copying-to-tmp-table-extremely-slow

Comment: Umh, it seems like you have no indexes.
Try this:
`ALTER TABLE sales 
    ADD KEY key_vendor(vendor),  
    ADD KEY key_salests(salests),  
    ADD KEY key_affilate(affiliate);`

`ALTER TABLE salesaff
    ADD KEY key_vendor(vendor),  
    ADD KEY key_salests(salests),  
    ADD KEY key_affilate(affiliate);`
then relaunch the query.

Comment: thanks. no key appears in two rows and key is null when select type is union.

Comment: added these indices but no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to order during the query execution. This might help:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(
 SELECT 'no' AS aff, ss.orderid,ss.saletype,ss.price,ss.salests 
    FROM sales ss 
    WHERE 1=1 AND 
        ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
  ) 

 UNION ALL 

 ( 
 SELECT 'yes' AS aff, sf.orderid,sf.saletype,sf.price,sf.salests 
 FROM salesaff sf 
 WHERE sf.vendor=sf.affiliate AND 
 sf.orderid IN (SELECT ss.orderid from sales ss WHERE 1=1 
               AND ( ss.vendor='3kpertrade' OR ss.affiliate='3kpertrade') 
               GROUP BY ss.orderid ) 
 ) 
)
ORDER BY salests DESC
```

Comment: Err:  Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Try to put aliases to the two queries that are in the union: select * from ( (query 1) a union all (query 2) b) order by...